# Is It possible to share an Open Graph Story on a Page as Admin?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to publish an Open Graph Story on a Facebook Page as an Admin. Is it possible ?

I'm currently able to post an open graph story on my wall or to publish a message as myself on the Facebook page.

I'm working with the Facebook iOS SDK.

So when using FBSDKShareAPI, How can I change the endpoint ? (Replace /me/feed by /page-id/feed)

Or when using FBSDKGraphRequest, How can I pass in parameter an FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you include your code?

Comment: add access token of particular  page to share

Comment: No, that is not possible. Open Graph _actions_ are something only users can undertake, not pages.